# Adding Aspect bean definition in java config is not letting create other beans

Tags: spring, aop

I am kind of new to spring and trying to add a simple advice to a simple method join point using @Aspect annotation in Spring.

I have used a simple interface and an implementing method

```
package aspect;
public interface Module {
public void getModuleName();
}

package aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class MyModule implements Module {
@Override
public void getModuleName() {
long t = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("My Module.");
long t1 = System.nanoTime()-t;
System.out.println("Execution time : "+t1);
}
}
```

One simple advice as below

```
package aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Aspect
public class MyDefinedAspectLogging {
@Pointcut("execution(* aspect.MyModule.getModuleName(..))")
public void dummy() {}  
@Before("dummy()")
public void beforeLog()
{
System.out.println("Log Before entering service");
}   
@After("dummy()")
public void AfterLog()
{
System.out.println("Log After returning from service");
}
}
```

My context config file is as below

```
package aspect;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses= {MyModule.class})
public class ConfigJava {
@Bean
public MyDefinedAspectLogging getMyDefinedAspectLogging() {
return new MyDefinedAspectLogging();
}
}
```

And I have implemented a simple class for testing as below

```
package aspect;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
public class Mainer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
ApplicationContext context = new 
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConfigJava.class);
MyModule m = context.getBean(MyModule.class);
m.getModuleName();
((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).close();
}
}
```

When I run this I am getting error as below

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [aspect.MyModule] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968)
    at aspect.Mainer.main(Mainer.java:12)
```

As per my understanding MyModule class should be created using component scan.

Inorder to test this I have commented my advice bean definition in java config as below

```
package aspect;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses= {MyModule.class})
public class ConfigJava {
/*  @Bean
public MyDefinedAspectLogging getMyDefinedAspectLogging() {
return new MyDefinedAspectLogging();
}*/
}
```

And after this I ran Main method of Mainer class and got below output

```
    Mar 16, 2018 7:17:35 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5fa7e7ff: startup date [Fri Mar 16 19:17:35 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    My Module.
    Execution time : 101664
    Mar 16, 2018 7:17:36 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext doClose
    INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5fa7e7ff: startup date [Fri Mar 16 19:17:35 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
```

What Am I missing here. Howcome defining advice bean is stopping the implementation bean creation in Spring context.

Some point I have tried but didn't get any success:

- I have used basePackages instead of basePackageClasses for value of @ComponentScan annotaion
- I have used @ComponentScan without any vaue
- I have tried defining MyModule bean inside java config instead of component scan.

Update:
I have tried using Module instead of MyModule in pointcut expression

```
@Pointcut("execution(* aspect.Module.getModuleName(..))")
public void dummy() {}
```

Comment: Spring uses proxies and by default JDK Dynamic proxies. You will get an object which behaves like a `Module` but which isn't a `MyModule`. In short use `getBean(Module.class)` instead of `getBean(MyModule.class).

Comment: Thank you , it works fine . But it made me even more confused.My understanding is MyModule is a singleton bean [I didnt define any scope] and hence bean will be created when spring context is loaded.Is this bean creation is via reflection or via proxy. I thought only aspects [in my case MyDefinedAspectLogging class] and beans with session and request scope are defined via proxy.

Comment: That singleton bean will be wrapped in a proxy to apply AOP.

Comment: @Deinum Thank you so much for the clarification .